# Rounding calculation with uncertainties at beginning or wait till absolute uncertainty?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Here is the question,

A projectile is measured to have a horizontal displacement of ($x=5.1 \pm 0.4$ m) after a flight time of ($t=0.4 \pm 0.1$ s). Calculate:

(i) the horizontal velocity ($V_h$)

(ii) using a calculus based approach, calculate the uncertainty in this velocity

(iii) restate the velocity with its associated uncertainty to the correct precision. Assume air resistance is negligible.

Using (horizontal velocity= horizontal distance/time), I get a value of 12.75 m/s. However I am not sure whether to round to 10 m/s since there is only 1sf for the time or to leave it as 12.75 until I calculate the absolute uncertainty.

$$
\frac{\Delta V_h}{V_h}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\Delta x}{x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\Delta t}{t}\right)^2}
$$

For this calculation I obtain differing values depending on whether I use 10 or 12.75. If use 12.75 I get ($\Delta Vh= \pm 4$ m/s) and thus round 12.75 get a final answer of $13\pm4$ m/s. But if use 10 I get ($\Delta V_h= \pm3$ m/s) and final answer of $10\pm3$ m/s.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to determine the significant figures of a computed quantity that carries uncertainty is to first compute its uncertainty. Then the quantity needs to match the *precision* of the uncertainty. Let us illustrate this by solving your problem.

(i) $V_h=\frac{x}{t}=\frac{5.1}{0.4}=12.75$ m/s. Keep this value, but this is not the final result (it may be, but there is no guarantee!).

(ii) The uncertainty of the velocity (which you denoted by $\Delta V_h$), is then computed by the formula you have given

$$
\Delta V_h=V_h\sqrt{\left(\frac{\Delta x}{x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\Delta t}{t}\right)^2}=12.75\sqrt{\left(\frac{0.4}{5.4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{0.1}{0.4}\right)^2}=(3.324474629\ldots) \text{ m}/\text{s}
$$

(iii) Now comes the part to truncate things. Usually, uncertainty is expressed with one or two significant figures (this varies a bit from professors/fields). But the correct procedure is to write down the uncertainty with the correct number of significant figures then round up the value of $V_h$ to match the same *precision* of the uncertainty (not the same number of significant figures!). Here it goes:

If you write $\Delta V_h$ with *one significant figure*, then $\Delta V_h=3$ m/s. Thus $\boxed{V_h=(13\pm3)\text{ m}/{s}}$.

If you write $\Delta V_h$ with *two significant figures*, then $\Delta V_h=3.3$ m/s. Thus $\boxed{V_h=(12.8\pm3.3)\text{ m}/{s}}$.

As I mentioned, there is no way to predict the number of significant figures before you compute the uncertainty. If the uncertainty had been $0.55$ m/s and you chose to write it down with two significant figures, then you would write $V_h=(12.75\pm0.55)\text{ m}/{s}$.

Hope this helps! Cheers.